# php mysql date filtering is creating some issue

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, date, filtering

I am trying to filter by date.
If I select from and to date and click filter button, the URL in the browser showing like this:

```
http://example.come/form.php?fromdate=01%2F04%2F2015&todate=01%2F21%2F2015
```

I will not get any data. But if I change URL with these parameters, the filter works and I get the data from backend.

```
http://example.come/form.php?fromdate=2015-01-04&todate=2015-01-21
```

Please guide me where I am making a mistake.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: change `date format` and do `urldecode()`

Comment: `URL encoding symbols` is the key

Comment: @RamSharma, Can you please elaborate more....
I am not getting your point...

Comment: as per first example you are using date format as dd-mm-yyyy which is not working but working example has yyyy-mm-dd format so change format only and use urldecode to convert special characters

Answer (score 0):

You are sending fromDate and toDate in mm/dd/yyyy format in the first URL.

In second URL you are sending fromDate and toDate in YYYY-MM-DD format.

MySql default date format is YYYY-MM-DD format. So, second URL is returning records.

Since in the first URL, the date format is MM/DD/YYYY format, it is not returning any records.

Try changing the date format of fromDate and toDate to **YYYY-MM-DD** format. It should work.